# How do I import Apple's UIImage+Effects category into my Swift app?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiview, uiimage

**Sample Project:** http://cl.ly/1I0c2E3D0x1z

I'm a little confused. I want to use [Apple's image blurring library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/UIImageEffects/Introduction/Intro.html) in my Swift project, but it seems like adding the .h and .m, putting the .h in my bridging header and compiling isn't sufficient.

It gives me tons of error (actually stops reporting them eventually) at compile time, the first bunch saying "Expected a type" and taking issue with `UIImage`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We definitely need more information, best would be a sample project where you reproduced the issue.

Comment: @HAS Added to main post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler doesn't recognize `UIImage`.

That is because you only import `Foundation` but `UIImage` is declared in `UIKit`.

Change line 50 in the `UIImageEffects.h` from

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
```

to

```
@import UIKit;
```

After that the projects builds without any problems!

---

In your Objective-C projects you most probably imported `UIKit` in your `.pch` precompiled headers file.

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes me feel rather foolish.

Comment: I wouldn't guess it by myself.TNX

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to your target's build settings:

1.In Xcode, if you go into the build settings for your target, and scroll all the way down you'll find a "Swift Compiler - Code Generation" section.

2.Set "Objective-C Bridging Header" to <#PROJECT_NAME>Bridging-Header.h

3.Now create a Bridging-Header.h file.Import sdk to Bridging-Header.h.

You did the same?If not then try this. This worked for me.